# Getting subscription & in-app purchase information from an App hosted in Microsoft store

Tags: java, spring-boot, uwp, windows-store, in-app-subscription

We have an app hosted in Microsoft store.
We want to,

1. Access the subscription/in-app purchase information of the app from backend using java/springboot
2. What are the MS Store Rest APIs that we can use to validate or communicate.

As we are doing this for first time any pointers or code sample will be absolutely halpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Any updates about your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the Response @RoyLi-MSFT ; it's resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Microsoft Store collection API* and *Microsoft Store purchase API* to access entitlement information for these products from your services. These APIs consist of REST methods that are designed to be used by developers with add-on catalogs that are supported by cross-platform services.  For example, *Microsoft Store collection API* could **query for products owned by a user** and *Microsoft Store purchase API* could **get subscriptions for a user**.

You could learn the full process about how to use the **Microsoft Store collection API** and **Microsoft Store purchase API** here:  **[Manage product entitlements from a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service)**. And if you want to get the subscription information of the user, you could take a look at **[Get subscriptions for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user)**, which contains the full request example and response body.